# Creating a config that overrides some Docker settings while keeping docker:publish behavior

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to create a SBT build that can publish a Docker container either to DockerHub or to our internal Docker repository. I'm using sbt-native-packager 1.0.3 to build the Docker image.

Here's an excerpt from my build.sbt:

```
dockerRepository in dockerInternal := Some("thomaso"),
packageName in dockerInternal := "externalname",
```

`sbt docker:publish` now successfully publishes to thomaso/externalname on DockerHub.

To add the option to publish to our internal Docker repo I added a configuration called dockerInternal:

```
val dockerInternal = config("dockerInternal") extend Docker
```

I then added these two settings to override the defaults:

```
dockerRepository in Docker := Some("docker.nrk.no/project"),
packageName in Docker := "internalname",
```

My expectation was that `sbt dockerInternal:publish` should publish a Docker image to docker.nrk.no/project/internalname. Instead, I get this error message:

```
delivering ivy file to   /home/n06944/repos/nrk.recommendations/api/target/scala-2.10/ivy-0.1-  SNAPSHOT.xml
java.lang.RuntimeException: Repository for publishing is not specified.
```

It seems to me SBT tried to publish to Ivy, not to Docker - when I hardcode the values to the internal repo the publishing works fine and there is no mention of Ivy in the logs. The Docker configuration modifies the publish task, and I hoped that by letting dockerInternal extend Docker I would inherit the Docker-specific publish behavior. Is that an incorrect assumption? Am I missing some incantations, or is there another approach that would be better?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import all the necessary task to your new config. sbt-native-packager recommends generating submodules for different packaging configurations.

If you want to fiddle around with configuration scopes (which gets pretty messy very fast) [here is another SO answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609347/how-do-i-create-a-tarball-and-a-zip-for-a-single-module-using-distinct-configura/35636347#35636347).

cheers,
Muki